# Android programming bitmap rotation

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a bitmap rotate and point towards the mouse but I get strange results:

Video: http://www.truploader.com/view/993341

The mouse isn't visible it does rotate, however it doesn't rotate to the tip of the mouse point.

Code:

```
     /**
    * Rotates the object based on a point
    */
 public void setRotation(float x, float y)
 {
  float XDistance = this.xPos - x;
        float YDistance = this.yPos - y;

        float Radians =  (float) Math.atan2(YDistance, XDistance);
        this.degrees = Math.round((Radians*180/Math.PI));

       this.moveObject();
       this.r.setRotate(this.degrees, this.picture.getWidth() / 2, this.picture.getHeight());  //origin of the base
  // this.r.setRotate(this.degrees, this.picture.getWidth() / 2, this.picture.getHeight() / 2);  
 }
```

Mouse position is x, and y. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you get the "mouse position"? I guess you take it from a MotionEvent, so notice this coordinates are relative to the target View origin.

Answer (score 0):

What results do you expect? `Rotates the object based on a point` could mean a lot of things. What is wrong with it?

Are the degrees correct? Initialize your object, fake a mouse position and see if `this.degrees` is what you expect it to be and what you need it to be. If it doesn't work, consider writing a unit test.

What does `this.moveObject();` do? Does it do, what it's supposed to do correctly?

`this.r.setRotate(` does it need degrees? Why `this.picture.getWidth() / 2`? About what point does it rotate?

So, what's wrong?